# Scheduled apex not firing email alert

Tags: apex, class, scheduled-apex

The apex class below did not fire an email, yet I have a record that should meet the criteria needed. The class is scheduled to run on every day of the week. Could anybody help explain why it has not run please?

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
    {
        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
        {
            sendEmailtoOppOwner();
        }

        public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
        {
            List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
            listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Make_unavailable_for_opps_and_proposals__c = TRUE)];

            for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity)
            {
               Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

               mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
               mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');
               mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
               mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + opportunitylineitem.Product2.Name);
               mail.setPlainTextBody(opportunity.Id +' has been created.');

               Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            }

            update listOpportunity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: any error? email deliverity is set to all email or not?

Comment: Please post your saved code..According to this  posted code.there are few errors which will not allow the class to be saved.For eg: mail.setPlainTextBody(opportunity.Id +' has been created.');                                 here opportunity variable does not exist

Comment: I've just reposted the code @PreyaMohandoss.

Comment: @Ratan deliverability is set to "All email" Is there anywhere else that I should check?

Comment: again your code has the same variable opportunity and opportunitylineitem.ARe you able to save this code without any error? I doubt the same..

Comment: goto setup --> quick find/search box type Scheduled Jobs --> check here if you get any error. you can find here... Also i guess your above code is not compiled successfully ?

Comment: I looked under Scheduled jobs and the job name is in this list, it said it ran today for the first time at 00:00 and that is scheduled to run again at 11/10/2016 at 00:00. @Ratan

Comment: @PreyaMohandoss The code i've posted is the saved code, so i've gone to develop > apex classes and copy/pased the code from this page.

Comment: glenn if you want to test your code right away i suggest direct call the sendEmailtoOppOwner method from developer console and check in debug log if you are getting exception or not?

Comment: @Ratan thanks very much for your help, buti'm not really a developer, how would i do this?

Comment: Please change the following                                                                                  mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + opp.opportunitylineitem.Product2.Name);
               mail.setPlainTextBody(opp.Id +' has been created.');                               Query the product2.name on the soql while querying opportunity line item.Then call the method from dev console

Comment: @Ratan I've figured out how to direct call the method, and an execution log has been produced. What should I be looking out for to see if there was an exception?

Comment: @Ratan There is an event called "Email_Queue" where it says 11:41:57:245 EMAIL_QUEUE [24]|replyTo: glenn.daly@live.com, subject: Historic Service attached to current opportunity : , senderDisplayName: Salesforce Support, bccSender: false, saveAsActivity: false, useSignature: true, targetObjectId: 005w0000004x3Ri, plainTextBody: Id has been created.,

Comment: @Ratan then a "Method Exit" 11:41:57:694 METHOD_EXIT [2]|01p26000000AikG|OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled.sendEmailtoOppOwner()

Comment: @Ratan I'm guessing it triggered if it says this no? 11:41:57:000 LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Number of Email Invocations: 1 out of 10

Comment: @PreyaMohandoss it says "Invalid foreign key relationship: Opportunity.opportunitylineitem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add below line as `setSaveAsActivity` default to `true` which is causing an Exception `INVALID_SAVE_AS_ACTIVITY_FLAG, saveAsActivity must be false when sending mail to users.`,

To avoid this exception set this value as `false`.

```
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
```